# How 2 change 'X' col. value of table on one click if each row of table represent in separate HTML forms with each submit button to change 'X' value?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have mysql employee table with cols = `(EmpID, ProjectCode, Date, StartTime, EndTime, NoOfHours, TaskPerformed, ModifiedDate, Status)`, Status consists of integer value either 1 (Billed) or 2 (Not billed) or 3 (Invoiced) or 4 (Uninvoiced), this status column values can be changed by the admin only.

so my problem is i am displaying each row values of table as different html form in PHP script with checkbox for status value where admin make a check on relevant i.e.particular entry should be billed or unbilled or invoiced or uninvoiced entry on reading the row values of employee table. but here problem comes on checking i need to make a post request for each form means i need to click on 10 buttons if i have 10 rows in a tables button i need to get the single button to submit all 10 form data.

please give direction.

below is if condition in `admindashboardentry.php` for matching if condition for retrieving table row values when the admin has specific selection for `EmpID, ProjectCode,StartDate, EndDate` i.e. admin provides values from a HTML Form in  `admindashboard.php` via method POST to these variable to get table rows from database.

```
if(isset($_POST['empidcheck']) and isset($_POST['projectcodecheck']) and isset($_POST['startdatecheck']) and isset($_POST['enddatecheck'])){

    $empid = $_POST['empid'];
    $projectcode = $_POST['projectcode'];
    $startdate = $_POST['startdate'];
    $enddate = $_POST['enddate'];

    //to make database connection
    include('connection.php');  

    echo "<p>Admin Entry Received: $empid, $projectcode, $startdate, $enddate</p>";

    //To Display Name and Employee ID above table Start

    $nameDisplaySql = "SELECT EmpID, Name FROM employee_data WHERE EmpID = '$empid'";

    $result = $conn->query($nameDisplaySql);                                            

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

            echo "<p>".$row["EmpID"]." - ".$row["Name"]."</p>";
            echo "<hr>";

        }
    }


    //To Display Name and Employee ID above table End

    $selectSql = "SELECT * FROM $empid WHERE EmpID = '$empid' AND ProjectCode = '$projectcode' AND Date BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate' ORDER BY Date DESC, ModifiedDate DESC";


    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $selectSql);


    $sumNoOfHours = 0.0;    

    displayTableHeading();                                                                                                                                                                          

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

        $sumNoOfHours = $sumNoOfHours + $row['NoOfHours'];

        displayTableRow($row);


    }

    tableEnding($sumNoOfHours);

    //form element to make the button below table to get the entry

    echo "<form action = 'admindashboardentry.php' method = 'post'>";
    echo "<input type ='hidden' name='empid' value= '$empid' >";
    echo "<input type ='hidden' name='projectcode' value= '$projectcode' >";
    echo "<input type ='hidden' name='startdate' value= '$startdate' >";
    echo "<input type ='hidden' name='enddate' value= '$enddate' >";
    echo "<input type='submit' name = 'allsetdownload' value = 'Download'>";
    echo "</form>";


}
```

Below are the functions for display row and heading to be used in displaying the rows of table. They are also in file `admindashboardentry.php`.

```
//Webpage Table Heading

function displayTableHeading(){

    // echo "<div class='heading'>";
    echo "<b>";
    echo "<input type='text'   size='7' value = 'EmpID' readonly>";
    echo "<input type='text' style='margin-left:2px;' size='8' value = 'Project Code' readonly>";
    echo "<input type='text' style='margin-left:2px;' size='6' value = 'Date'  readonly>";
    echo "<input type='text' style='margin-left:2px;' size='7' value = 'Start Time' readonly>";
    echo "<input type='text' style='margin-left:2px;' size='7' value = 'End Time'  readonly>";
    echo "<input type='text' style='margin-left:2px;' size='8' value = 'No Of Hours'  readonly>";
    echo "<input type='text' style='margin-left:2px;' size='17' value = 'Task Performed'  readonly>";
    echo "<input type='text' style='margin-left:2px;' size='14' value = 'Modified Date' readonly>";
    echo "</b>";
    // echo "</div>";
}

//Webpage Table Row

function displayTableRow($row){


    $taskstr = $row['TaskPerformed'];
    $modifieddate = $row['ModifiedDate'];   




    echo "<form action='admindashboardentry.php' method = 'post'>";

    echo "<input type='text' style='margin-top:2px;' name='empid' size='8' value =".$row['EmpID']." readonly>";                                 
    echo "<input type='text'  style='margin-top:2px; margin-left:2px;' name='projectcode' size='8' value =".$row['ProjectCode']." readonly>";
    echo "<input type='text'  style='margin-top:2px; margin-left:2px;' name='date' size='8' value =".$row['Date']." readonly>";
    echo "<input type='text'  style='margin-top:2px; margin-left:2px;' name='stime' size='8' value =".$row['StartTime']." readonly>";
    echo "<input type='text'  style='margin-top:2px; margin-left:2px;' name='etime' size='8' value =".$row['EndTime']." readonly>";
    echo "<input type='text'  style='margin-top:2px; margin-left:2px;' name='hours' size='8' value =".$row['NoOfHours']." readonly>";
    echo "<input type='text'  style='margin-top:2px; margin-left:2px;' name='taskperformed' size='20' value = '$taskstr'>";
    echo "<input type='text'  style='margin-top:2px; margin-left:2px;' name='modifieddate' size='15' value = '$modifieddate' readonly>";

    echo "<span>&nbsp</span><input id='checkBox1' style='margin-top:2px; margin-left:2px;' type='checkbox' name='billed' > <span style='font-weight:bold;'>Billed</span> ";
    echo "<span>&nbsp</span><input id='checkBox2' style='margin-top:2px; margin-left:2px;' type='checkbox' name= 'notbilled'> <span style='font-weight:bold;'>Not Billed</span>";
    echo "<span>&nbsp</span><input id='checkBox3' style='margin-top:2px; margin-left:2px;' type='checkbox' name='invoiced'> <span style='font-weight:bold;'>Invoiced</span>";
    echo "<span>&nbsp</span><input id='checkBox4' style='margin-top:2px; margin-left:2px;' type='checkbox' name='uninvoiced'> <span style='font-weight:bold;'>Uninvoiced</span>";

    echo "<span>&nbsp</span><input type='submit' id='button' style='margin-top:2px; margin-left:2px; ' name = 'submit' style='margin-left:10px;'>";


    echo "</form>";                                                             


}
```